# SSRS Rollup Fields for Rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I am working on a report where I have employee time information along with dates for the time. Currently I have the tablix grouped by Employee and Date so that I only get time for that employee and date, however I get a row for each date:

[image]

What I am trying to do is drop the Date column and have the time for each Date rollup into it's specific date column (i.e. 7/16/2020 data would rollup into only the 7/16/2020 column header) and only have a single row for each employee. Desired output:

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can create a matrix report with Row group and column group. Check below screen shot to get desired output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a Matrix control instead of a table, add a row group by Employee (as you have already) ad then add a column group by date. This will give you the desired results.